# Google Fit steps do not match with History Api response

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

Got a problem with Google Fit steps integration. The customers complain that the numbers imported from the Google Fit are not the same as the ones Google Fit shows in its own Fit app.

As per [Google Fit documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total) *“to get the same daily step count as the Fit app”* we do the following:

```
val startDateTime = DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusDays(14).millis
val endDateTime = DateTime.now().millis

val datasource = DataSource.Builder()
    .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
    .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
    .build()

val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
    .aggregate(datasource)
    .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .setTimeRange(startDateTime, endDateTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build()

GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)?.let {
    Fitness.getHistoryClient(context, it)
        .readData(readRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener { dataReadResponse ->
            repository.readAndSaveBuckets(dataReadResponse)
        }
}
```

However it doesn’t seem to work in every case.

For example, for Apr 4th it shows 6649 steps.
If I go to “See source data” there will be 88 records.
If I summarise all of them, I’ll get 7362 but I guess that’s okay, since Google Fit removes some of the overlapping entries by applying some smart logic.

So I’m trying to get those 6649 steps to my app but the code above returns

```
StartDateTime                   EndDateTime                     Steps
2022-04-04T08:59:56.072+0200    2022-04-04T09:00:00.000+0200    2
2022-04-04T09:00:00.000+0200    2022-04-04T09:15:33.084+0200    1661
2022-04-04T09:45:53.807+0200    2022-04-04T09:54:41.917+0200    806
2022-04-04T16:50:06.160+0200    2022-04-04T16:51:06.160+0200    10
2022-04-04T17:03:21.121+0200    2022-04-04T17:16:18.422+0200    23
2022-04-04T17:46:09.064+0200    2022-04-04T17:47:09.064+0200    11
2022-04-04T18:33:57.089+0200    2022-04-04T18:42:31.094+0200    682
2022-04-04T19:11:41.109+0200    2022-04-04T19:30:00.000+0200    926
2022-04-04T19:30:00.000+0200    2022-04-04T19:43:56.096+0200    1648
```

2+1661+806+10+23+11+682+926+1648 = 5769 (not 6649)

For many other dates this code works just fine: I get the same numbers as in the Google Fit app. So I assume it’s some sort of a bug on Google Fit side or I don’t know some magic piece of knowledge.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just found this reference in the doc that could help you out.

"The Google Fit app shows this more accurate, estimated step count on both the Android and iOS app, and the Google Fit app on smart watches with Wear OS.

If you read by your app's data source rather than by data type, and your app only uses local step data, the step count will be different from the step count in the Google Fit app.

If you're reading the data types but values are still different from the Google Fit app, this temporary difference in numbers could be due to syncing delays."

Comment: Hey! Were you able to figure this out?